# If I cast Silent Image on a boat, does the illusion move with the boat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, illusion

**If I cast Silent Image on a boat, does it move with the boat or do I have to use an action to make it move with the boat?**

The situation is this, my party is floating down a large river and I want to be able to use the Silent Image spell on the canoe to make it look like a large tree floating down the river to anyone from the tree line.

My assumption is that because I've placed the illusion on the floor of the canoe, it will just stick with the boat and I do not need to use an action to move it because the illusion is not moving but rather the canoe is moving and the illusion is just place on the canoe.

Of course, the illusion isn't perfect because part of the tree looks like someone started carving the bottom of a boat out of it, and well the tree has oddly positioned branches that obscure much of the part of the tree (where the ores might be seen while the party paddles.), but it's a tree non the less, especially to the passive observer.

Comment: While answers to both this question and the alleged duplicate are essentially, "Spells only do what they say they do," the questions are different.  This question is focused on action economy: "Do I have to use an action to move the effect of this specific spell?" Where the alleged duplicate is asking, "Does a spell move with its target?" I say they are different questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't looking at the spell in those terms. Now that I think about it, I guess the only question is if I consider a canoe an object or a spot within range. Reguardless, of what I choose though I should be able to move the illusion where ever the canoe goes since if I am on the canoe, it is always within range of the spell.